# preg_match_all find string not "http" and after #

Tags: regex, preg-match-all

I need to find a string not containing `https` or `http`, but after `#`
Demo:

```
#abc => find.
http://google.com/#abc => not find.
```

My code is find content after # 
preg_match_all("/#([^\s]+)/", $content, $matches);

Comment: Please be more precise on your actual input and output strings. Your goal could be achieved in various ways.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you

```
^(http://)(?#)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you first want to make sure the string is an URL and after that get everything behind the hashbang? (including the hashbang). Then I believe this regex with a non-capturing group will work:

```
preg_match_all('/^(?:https*:\/\/.*)(#.*)$/', $url, $matches);
```

I suspect you are using php :)

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?!https?://).*?$
```

you can look here: [regax](http://regexr.com/v1?3920p)